# What is the meaning of "ward"?

Tags: verb

I was reading an article and I came a cross this word "ward" and could not find the translation of it in this sentence:

> Von ihren Schwestern **ward** ihr nichts als Hohn und Spott zuteil.

Comment: Didn't exactly search much, did you? Even Duden has it: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ward

Comment: "`Es werde Licht! Und es ward Licht`"

Answer (score 4):

The verb form »ward« is just an outdated form of »werden«. The modern form (in this sentence, i.e. 3<sup>rd</sup> person) is »wurde«.

For more details see https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:werden Indikativ, Präteritum, Aktiv, Singular, all three persons.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I actually thought that it has the same meaning as werden but did not get the story behind it :)

Comment: Then why did you not accept his answer? Doing so woudl help others who read this question in future, just as others here have helped you.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica: The user Mohanad has posted this question more than 3 years ago, and this, and the comment to my answer was the only two activities that this user ever performed. He never asked another question, he didn't post any answer and he posted only 1 comment. And this all on 1 day in April 2017, within a period of 2 hours. It is very unlikely, that he ever will come back. So he never will read your comment, and he never will accept my answer. And nobody else but him can do this.

Comment: Sad. So many do this - they ask for and accept help, then don't show any courtesy, or help others in return. Sometimes I add a reminder like this, even if know that the OP is not coming back, because maybe it will educate someone else. `I'm looking at ***you***, future readers !!!`